# Graphileon How to change data store configuration

Tags: neo4j, graphileon

Graphileon Is not showing me settings screen again , i want to change db configutaion

i reinstalled app then also its same login screen

What to do ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can edit the Graphileon **config.json** file and adjust it for the new configuration of your application store. If you reset the stores and admins sections as indicated below, the settings screen will be triggered on restart of the application.

```
"stores": {},
"admins": [],
```

Alternatively you can delete the whole config.json file as a whole and then restart the application. There is no need to remove other Graphileon related files to trigger the settings screen.

For Windows users the config.json can be found in 
    C:\Users\**yourusername**\AppData\Roaming\Graphileon\config

Answer (score 0):

Go to windows search bar and delete whatever comes with "Graphileon" Name.It worked for me.But every time it will be killing